# Best way to handle session affinity in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, networking, server, routes

I have two instance in app engine, serving issue on dependent api call between servers, I have used session affinity to solve the issue, in my Nodejs API call (Export CSV) 2 fails out of 5. Is there any ttl to set for session affinity in app engine?

```
   network:
      session_affinity: true
```

Comment: Are you on GAE standard or flexible?  It might be only for flexible.

Comment: Flexible @newname

Answer (score 2):

2 fails out of 5 could be due to an overloaded instance.

And It is not possible to set TTL for session affinity in `App engine`.  The only solution is to use `Google cloud Load balancer` to set an affinity cookie TTL.

You can achieve this by enabling flag [`--affinity-cookie-ttl=AFFINITY_COOKIE_TTL`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/create#--affinity-cookie-ttl) while creating backend services.

Comment: Let me try with Load balancer.